# Using atlas in QGIS server GetPrint?

Tags: qgis, qgis-server, getprint

I have a QGIS project that utilizes an atlas to change the symbology and map extents based on a vector layer's features. I'm looking to use QGIS server to create and serve PDFs on demand.

Is there a way to utilize this functionality in a QGIS server GetPrint request?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the [qgis-atlasprint](https://github.com/3liz/qgis-atlasprint) python QGIS server (2.18) plugin